# Proof of fundamental theorem of calculus one moment of undestanding

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

guys! I have at the university this proof of fundamental theorem of calculus. But I didn't understand one moment. Can u may be explain it? Let be $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ continuous function.
We start with $\forall x\in[a,b] \quad F(x):=\int_a^bf(t)dt$.
We restrict the function. $f:[a,x]\to \mathbb R$ Now let be $x,c \in[a,b]$ with $x>c $ then we have $\int_a^cf(t)dt$+$\int_c^xf(t)dt$=$\int_a^xf(t)dt.$ Or with our definition $F(x)-F(c)=\int_c^xf(t)dt$. Now since $\int_c^xf(c)dx=f(c)\cdot(x-c)$ just integral of constand function,it follows that $\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}-f(c)=\frac{1}{x-c}\int_c^x(f(t)-f(c))dt$. Now we know, that $f$ is uniformly continuous and we have:$\exists\delta>0, \forall x\in [a,b],\quad(||x-c||<\delta \implies$ $||\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}-f(c)||\leq\frac{1}{x-c}\cdot(x-c)\cdot sup{||f(t)-f(c)||:t\in[c,x]=\epsilon}$).1 question is what do we need the uniformly
continuity of $f$ and how from this inequality we can conclude, that $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}=f(c)$ so $F'=f$. Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

Take $\varepsilon>0$; since the goal is to prove that $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}=f(c)$, you want, by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit, to prove that, for some $\delta>0$,$$|x-c|<\delta=\left|\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}-f(c)\right|<\varepsilon.$$This is the same thing as proving that$$|x-c|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{\int_c^xf(t)-f(c)\,\mathrm dt}{x-c}\right|<\varepsilon.$$It is here that uniform continuity is important: since $f$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is a closed and bounded interval, then $f$ is uniformly continuous, and therefore there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|t-c|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(c)\bigr|<\varepsilon$. And, for such a $\delta$, we have\begin{align}\left|\frac{\int_c^xf(t)-f(c)\,\mathrm dt}{x-c}\right|&=\frac{\left|\int_c^xf(t)-f(c)\,\mathrm dt\right|}{|x-c|}\\&\leqslant\frac{\int_c^x\bigl|f(t)-f(c)\bigr|\,\mathrm dt}{|x-c|}\\&<\frac{|x-c|\varepsilon}{|x-c|}\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: Thank u! It was very helpful. Can u explain, why is $\int_a^b|f(t)-f(c)|dt<|x-c|\cdot\epsilon$ ?

Comment: It was a typo! I meant $\int_c^x$, as in the rest of the proof.